# CSS Grid > how to make side columns fluid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid layout with 14 columns. I would like to make the left and right columns to be fluid and resize together with browser window.
Let me explain using this picture:
[image: 14 cols grid]

Note: red frame is the screen size.

**1.** Yellow columns are fully visible, the same as other columns in the grid (width: 1fr)

**2.** On smaller screen 12 columns in the middle stays the same, but yellow columns get smaller and disapper like on **3.**
After that the whole layout gets smaller like on **4**.

Here I created a pen with this layout:

https://codepen.io/Reystleen/pen/LYbgjdY

```
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
    <div class="grid-col"></div>
  </div>

  .grid {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     z-index: 1;
     width: 100%;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
     max-width: 1600px;
     margin: 0 auto; 
     border-left: 1px solid grey;
  }
  .grid-col {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     height: 100vh;
     border-right: 1px solid grey;
  }
  .grid-col:first-child,
  .grid-col:last-child {
     background-color: yellow;
  }
```

I tried to use minmax, min-width, but no success.
Is it even possible? I would appreciate any help here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make them with `1fr`. Here is an idea using `clamp(0px,9vw - 30px,100%/14)` . This will make your value between `0px` as min and `100%/14` as max (equal to 1fr since you are dividing your grid into 14). The middle value is variable value that will decrease based on the screen size.

it's equal to `Xvw - Ypx`. `Y` is a fixed value and `X` is variable so the overal will decrease when the size of the screen decrease. There is no specific logic in the formula I used. You can edit it like you want.

```css
.grid {
  --mw:1600px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 
    clamp(0px,9vw - 30px,100%/14) repeat(12, 1fr)  
    clamp(0px,9vw - 30px,100%/14);
  max-width: var(--mw);
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 
    1px 0 0 grey,
    -1px 0 0 grey;
}

.grid-col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 
    1px 0 0 grey inset,
    -1px 0 0 grey inset;
}

.grid-col:first-child,
.grid-col:last-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Like below if you want to first resize the edges. when the screen is bigger than `1600px` we will have `min(1600px/14,1600px/12)` (100% will be 1600px since we defined a max value) so we take the first value. In the middle, we have 12 columns of `1600px/14` and it will logically remain 2 of `1600px/14` for each side.

When the screen start to decrease the `1600px/14` is fixed so only the `1fr` will decrease until we reach the point where `100%/12` will be smaller than `1600px/14` and in this case we have 12 columns of 100%/12 and `0` for each side

```css
.grid {
  --mw:1600px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr repeat(12, min(var(--mw)/14,100%/12) ) 1fr;
  max-width: var(--mw);
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 
    1px 0 0 grey,
    -1px 0 0 grey;
}

.grid-col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 
    1px 0 0 grey inset,
    -1px 0 0 grey inset;
}

.grid-col:first-child,
.grid-col:last-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
  <div class="grid-col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: *Sad front-end dev noises

Comment: I'm upvoting, theres real effort and knowledge here, good answer.

Comment: Thanks! It's close to what I wanted and I learnt about clamp function. Ideally I want the side columns to resize first (to 0) and after that the rest.

Comment: @Temani Afif WOW! This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot! The only thing.. I don't understand your solution, could you briefly explain this magic?

Comment: @Temani Afif Pure genius!! All clear now, thanks!